# How to make 2 (or more) custom post type post pages sit under the same slug?

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've created 2 `custom post types` like so:

```
register_post_type(
    'resources',
    theme_build_post_args(
        // $slug, $singular, $plural
        'resources', 'Resource', 'Resources',
        array(
            'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
            'menu_position' => 20,
            'has_archive'   => true,
            'public'        => true,
            'supports'          => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('tags'),
            // 'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'resources' ),
        )
    )
);

register_post_type(
  'video-demos-tours',
  theme_build_post_args(
    // $slug, $singular, $plural
    'video-demos-tours', 'Video Demos & Tours', 'Video Demos & Tours',
    array(
      'menu_icon' => get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/build/vectors/backend-icon.svg',
      'menu_position' => 23,
      'has_archive'     => true,
      'public'          => true,
      'supports'            => array('title', 'revisions', 'thumbnail', 'editor', 'author'),
      'taxonomies'      => array('tags'),
      // 'rewrite' => array('slug' => 'resources'),
    )
  )
);
```

`video-demo-tours` shares the same `single-` template as the `resources` post type, via this function:

```
function custom_single_template($single_template) {
  global $post;
  if (in_array($post->post_type, array('video-demos-tours'))) {
    return get_stylesheet_directory() . '/single-resources.php';
  }
  return $single_template;
}

add_filter('single_template', 'custom_single_template');
```

All posts from `resources` and `video-demos-tours` are being shown on `/resources`

But, when I click into a `video-demos-tours` post, the URL is `/video-demos-tours/post-name`. I want it to be `/resources/post-name`.

To do this, I've tried `rewrite`:

```
function custom_post_type_permalink($url, $post) {
    if (in_array($post->post_type, array('resources', 'video-demos-tours'))) {
        return home_url("resources/{$post->post_type}/{$post->post_name}/");
    }
    return $url;
}

add_filter('post_type_link', 'custom_post_type_permalink', 10, 2);
```

But, it didn't change anything (have flushed permalinks after too).

Any ideas?